# Redux is not working while using combine reducer

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm new to redux and react native as well .I am trying to initialize a basic store from a root reducer with initial state. While connecting root reducer to store my redux is not working. But when I'm connecting a single reducer to store my redux is working.

**RootReducer.js**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import cartItemsReducer from './CartItems';
import {CounterReducer} from './Counter';

const RootReducer = combineReducers({
  cartItemsReducer,
  CounterReducer,
});

export default RootReducer;
```

**CartItems.js**

```
import {ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_FROM_CART} from '../Actions/ActionTypes';

const initialState = [];

const cartItemsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
      return state.filter((cartItem) => cartItem.id !== action.payload.id);
  }
  return state;
};

export default cartItemsReducer;
```

**Counter.js**

```
import {INCREASE_COUNT, DECREASE_COUNT} from '../Actions/ActionTypes';

const InitialState = {
  count: 0,
};

export const CounterReducer = (state = InitialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INCREASE_COUNT:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count + 1,
      };
    case DECREASE_COUNT:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count - 1,
      };
  }
  return state;
};
```

**store.js**

```
import RootReducer from '../Reducers/RootReducer';

export const store = createStore(RootReducer);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import AppNavigator from './src/AppNavigator';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {store} from './src/Redux/Store/store';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppNavigator />
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**CounterComponent.js**

I'm using function component for my application

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import AppHeader from '../Common/AppHeader';
import CustomButton from '../Common/CustomButton';
import CustomText from '../Common/CustomText';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {INCREASE_COUNT, DECREASE_COUNT} from '../Redux/Actions/ActionTypes';
const CounterComponent = () => {
  const Counters = useSelector((state) => state.count);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const IncreaseCount = () => {
    dispatch({type: INCREASE_COUNT});
  };
  const DecreaseCount = () => {
    dispatch({type: DECREASE_COUNT});
  };
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
      <AppHeader HeaderName="Counter" isLeft={true} leftIconName="arrowleft" />
      <View style={{width: 150, alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 20}}>
        <CustomButton ButtonName="+" onPress={() => IncreaseCount()} />
        <CustomText value={Counters} style={{textAlign: 'center'}} />
        <CustomButton ButtonName="-" onPress={() => DecreaseCount()} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default CounterComponent;
```

Why is my usage of combineReducers not working in the same way as when I use the single rootreducer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after you combine the reducers, your state becomes the following:

```
               store
                /\
               /  \
              /    \
cartItemsReducer   CounterReducer
```

so you need to reference counter like so:

state.CounterReducer.count

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Wen W's answer, if you log your 'state', you'll see an object with both your reducers in there. That is why you need to access reducers by name after combining them.

Just change this line:

```
const Counters = useSelector((state) => state.CounterReducer.count);
```